# How to do a PUT request with curl and Authorization?

Tags: php, curl

This is what I am trying

```
$url = "https://aon-test.yui.com/api/".$this->_token."/".$action; 
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type:application/xml' ,
            'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("s!YIYIYIYIUYIY:X")
        );
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30000);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($xml));
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

I am getting 500 - Internal server error. 
What mistake I am doing here?

Comment: Please check to php error_log file

Comment: Checked, its not showing any error.

Comment: If you get `500` internal server error, there should be an error. If it is not displayed in browser, it should be exist in error log

Comment: Does this put request using CURL looks correct ?